# Can Gomega's Equal() handle multiple values ?

Tags: unit-testing, go, ginkgo, gomega

I am testing a function to send a mock request to a server using gomega and I want to verify that 1. the request has started 2. the request has completed. For this I am returning two booleans. They should both evaluate to true in the example below but the values will be subject to change. I have tried this:

```
g := gomega.NewGomegaWithT(t)
...
g.Eventually(func() (bool, bool) {
...
    start = false
    end = true

    if (request.status == "started") {
        start = true
    }
    if (request.status == "complete") {
        end = true
    }
    return start, end
}).Should(Equal((true, true))
```

But it seems that gomega's `Equal()` does not handle multiple variables. Is there any way around this? Is it bad practice to evaluate two return values ?

Comment: How can something be complete if it has never started? Checking for "complete" should suffice.

Comment: I believe `start` and `end` are  sample names, we can have as many return values as r1, r2, r3... without any particular meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wrapper function I wrote based on your pseudocode

```
g := gomega.NewGomegaWithT(t)
...
testedFunc := func() (bool, bool) {
...
    start = false
    end = true

    if (request.status == "started") {
        start = true
    }
    if (request.status == "complete") {
        end = true
    }
    return start, end
}

g.Eventually(func() map[string]bool{
    r1,r2 := testedFunc()
    return map[string]bool{"start": r1, "end": r2}
}).Should(Equal(map[string]bool{"start": true, "end": true}))
```

I'm using a map instead of simple `r1&r2`for verbosity, so, you can see what is actually wrong with the results. In my opinion, it's a bad practice to compare 2 return values unless the second one is an error. You can always combine multiple return values in a single language construct (map, slice, struct, etc.) as I did in my wrapper function. I understand it's hard to do with the async Eventually method, but in general, I'd try to assert each of the return values separately.

Answer (score 1):

In [`gomega`'s doc](https://onsi.github.io/gomega/#eventually), It has been said that multiple return is ok to be used.

> The function that you pass to Eventually can have more than one return
>   value. In that case, Eventually passes the first return value to the
>   matcher and asserts that all other return values are nil or
>   zero-valued. This allows you to use Eventually with functions that
>   return a value and an error – a common pattern in Go

In your code, can you change this line

`.Should(Equal((true, true))` to `.Should(Equal(true, true)`.

That should fix the problem.

**Edit:**

I overlooked that Equal only receives one interface parameter. My bad.

For future reference, for comparing multiple values in gomega's `eventually`,`Array` of struct (or any datatype) can be useful.

Comment: ..and asserts that all other return values are nil or zero-valued, so, then the test will never pass if the function returns true and true.

Comment: I see. I only focused on Eventually functions. I overlooked that `Equal` only receives one interface parameter. My bad.