# Can Gomega support verification of multiple return values of different types where the last one is not `error`?

Tags: unit-testing, go, ginkgo, gomega

For instance:
If I have a wrapper for https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map.Load:
with the same method signature:

```
func Load(key string) (value interface{}, ok bool)
```

in [Can Gomega's Equal() handle multiple values ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828807/can-gomegas-equal-handle-multiple-values) similar question was asked and the response is to put the return values into single data structure. If that is the case, what if I don't want to adapt the (production) code based on this limitation of the unit test framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done in several lines.

```
        value, ok := m.Load(key)
        Expect(value).NotTo(BeNil())
        Expect(ok).To(BeTrue())
```